# Relation popup display using Lizmap

Tags: qgis, lizmap, relation

The qgis popup shows the relationship records in the correct order based on the ID field, from 1 to 26.

[image]

The Lizmap popup instead shows the relationship records backwards, from 26 to 1.

How can this be fixed?

[image]